# Is my nutch work flow correct?

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

I am using the following commands to fetch data and want to check the url crawled. But I get empty file in output. Please tell what is wrong.

```
nutch inject dmoz -crawlId 1
nutch readdb -crawlId 1 -stats
nutch generate -crawlId 1
nutch fetch 1438535695-540986939 -crawlId 1 -threads 4
nutch updatedb 1438535695-540986939 -crawlId 1 
nutch readdb -crawlId 1 -dump output
```

I am using nutch v2.3 with Cassandra v2.2.

Comment: You are using Nutch with Cassandra, why don't you get data from Cassandra?

Comment: @LeQuocDo I have looked into the Cassandra table but I dont understand some fields. Nutch command should give complete interpreted information.

Comment: you can have a look nutch/conf/gora-cassandra-mapping.xml to understand the fields. Another thing is that why you did not run parse job after fetch job?